# How to preprocess data for Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter, data-preprocessing, whitenoise

I am reading through a Kalman filter techniques and thinking about how to use them but I am not sure if I understand the whole process in using the measured data in Kalman data-step.

Lets assume that you have accelerometer and you want to estimate speed. You create a Kalman filter with acceleration, velocity and bias states, and time-step and data-step with their equations. You know the accelerometer's and bias noise variances.

Now, the Kalman filter assumes by definition that the measurement noise is white which is flawed because most of the time it is colored in some way. My questions:

- If you use low pass filter to get rid of most of the high frequency noise, the noise won't be white so that is not going to work neither, right?
- Is the data preprocessing worth focusing on?
- Do you know any techniques/books/articles to fix that? What information do you need about the problem to decide which actions to take?
- Are there any data rejection algorithms that are used?

I read a little about that you can use Kalman as whitening filter too but I am not sure how to incorporate that into Kalman I described above.